# Magento 2.4 : I installed elastic search, but when i run start command to run elastic search it will give error

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento2.4

I installed elastic search, but when i run start command to run elastic search it will give error[image], and there is no error in log files in /var/log/elasticsearch

[image]

I am adding log files also, and i am using aws ubuntu 20.04 t2.micro
[image]

[image]

Comment: what's the elasticsearch version? is it 7.6+?

Comment: Yes, it's 7.+ version

Comment: You must install and configure Elasticsearch 7.6.x before upgrading to Magento 2.4.0. -  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 1):

as you can see from the log, you don't have enough memory to run full stack.
you have 2 options:

1. run ELK from AWS service
2. get bigger instance or set memory limits for ELK stack

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html

> **Setting the heap size:**
>
> By default, Elasticsearch tells the JVM to use a heap with a minimum
> and maximum size of 1 GB. When moving to production, it is important
> to configure heap size to ensure that Elasticsearch has enough heap
> available.
>
> Elasticsearch will assign the entire heap specified in jvm.options via
> the Xms (minimum heap size) and Xmx (maximum heap size) settings. You
> should set these two settings to be equal to each other.

> The value for these settings depends on the amount of RAM available on your server:

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this for Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt-cache search openjdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk
java -version
sudo gedit /etc/environment
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
echo $JAVA_HOME
sudo curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add - (OK)
sudo echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
sudo gedit /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

cluster.name: my-application
node.name: magentocom
network.publish_host: localhost
discovery.seed_hosts: []
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
cluster.initial_master_nodes: 127.0.0.1

sudo journalctl -xe

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
http://localhost:9200/
```

Hope this solves your issue !!!